# How the output of program came?

Tags: java

The output of following program is:

> ```
> superstatic block
> static blockn0  
> inmain  
> super constructor  
> constructor
> ```

Here is the code:

```
 class StaticSuper{
    static {
           System.out.println("superstatic block");
    }
    StaticSuper(){
           System.out.println("super constructor");
    }
 }

 public class StaticClassExample extends StaticSuper{
      static int rand;

      static {
           rand =(int) (Math.random() * 6);
           System.out.println("static blockn" + rand);
      }
      StaticClassExample(){
           System.out.println("constructor");
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("inmain");
           StaticClassExample st= new StaticClassExample();
      }
 }
```

Why "inmain" is printed third though it is first in the `main()`?  Please explain me the meaning of:

```
static {
 // some lines
}
```

in the class.

Comment: Is it homework? What are your ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you to learn java initialization order, take a look at static blocks too. also, i would suggest u to learn the magic of search

Answer (score 2):

The `static` block you're seeing is what we call a **static initializer** and its job is usually to initialize something in the class (perhaps a class-wide state or some kind of resource).

It is invoked **when the class is loaded** by the runtime and that's why it may be run before `main` is run.

Answer (score 0):

1 : when you create an instance by using new == > it calls the constructor

2 : just when you constructor is called , the parent constructor is called

3 : and also whenever a class is loaded , even for a constructor , the static blocks are executed first ,

thus you get the order you are getting

since you are executing you class , the complete files is checked first for any static block , and static blocks are executed even before the main method gets called

Answer (score 0):

> Please explain me the meaning of static { // some lines } in the
>   class.

It's called a [*static initializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7). It's executed when the class is loaded (or initialized, to be exact). The static blocks will be executed before your `main()`method.

---

> Why "inmain" is printed third though it is first in the main()?

Since static blocks are executed before your `main()`, it appears third in the print list and when you create the instance of `StaticClassExample` class, first its `parent` constructor is called and then its own constructor is called.

Hence, the output.

Answer (score 0):

Static blocks are called at the time classes are loaded. Thats why print outs of static are printed first. 
Static variable means that there won't be separate copies of that variable for different instances of that class. 
Static block of code is simply if you want to execute something at the time of class loading.